# While loop and diamond operator in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to input a text file to Perl program and reverse its order of lines i.e. last line will become first, second last will become second etc. I am using following code

```
#!C:\Perl64\bin

$k = 0; 
while (<>){
    print "the value of i is $i";
    @array[k] = $_;
    ++$k;
}

print "the array is @array";
```

But for some reason, my array is only printing the last line of the text file.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Pretty sure one element is a scalar context, so you need `$array[k]`.

Comment: And you can format code by indenting it 4 spaces, or select it and hit ctrl-k or the `{}` button.

Comment: You'll find it easier in the long run if you include `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your code. Experts use them to make sure they haven't made any silly mistakes; beginners should do so too. It would surely have reported a number of the issues diagnosed in the answer you've been given.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: thanks...they are pretty useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, rather than keep a separate array index, perl programs use the `push` operator to push a string onto an array.  One way to do this in your program:

```
push @array, $_;
```

If you really want to do it by array index, then you need to use the following syntax:

```
$array[$k] = $_;
```

Notice the `$` rather than `@` in front.  This tells perl that you're dealing with a single element from the array, not multiple elements.  `@array` gives you the entire array, while `$array[$k]` gives you a single element.  (There is a more advanced topic called "slices," but let's not get into that here.  I will say that `@array[$k]` gives you a slice, and that isn't what you want here.)

If you really just want to slurp the entire file into an array, you can do that in one step:

```
@array = ( <> );
```

That will read the entire file into `@array` in one step.

You might have noticed I omitted/ignored your `print` statement.  I'm not sure what it's doing printing out a variable named `$i`, since it didn't seem connected at all to the rest of the code.  I reasoned it was debug code you had added, and not really relevant to the task at hand.

Anyway, that should get your input into `@array`.  Now reversing the array... There are many ways you could do this in perl, but I'll let you discover those yourself.

Comment: Hi Joe,Thanks for the response. $array[$k] fixed the issue but i have another code i.e.#!C:\Perl64\bin 
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10){
@array[$i] = "string";
++$i;}

print "the array value is @array"; For this code i am using @array[$i] within while loop but this seems to be giving correct output i.e. any array with 10 elements all having string.

Comment: As I mentioned above, `@array[$i]` gives you a slice, and that's not quite what you're looking for here.  (It's a slice with one element, so it'll happen to work, but it isn't correct.)  My local copy of perl gives this warning:  `Scalar value @array[$i] better written as $array[$i] at ./slice.pl line 9.`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
@array[k] = $_;
```

you want:

```
$array[$k] = $_;
```

To reference the scalar variable $k, you need the $ on the front. Without that it is interpreted as the literal string 'k', which when used as an array index would be interpreted as 0 (since a non-numeric string will be interpreted as 0 in a numeric context).

So, each time around the loop you are setting the first element to the line read in (overwriting the value set in the previous iteration).

A few other tips:

- @array[ ] is actually the syntax for an array slice rather than a single element. It works in this case because you are assigning to a slice of 1. The usual syntax for accessing a single element would be $array[ ].
- I recommend placing 'use strict;' at the top of your script - you would have gotten an error pointing out the incorrect reference to $k
- Instead of using an index variable, you could push the values onto the end of the array, eg:

  ```
  while (<>) {
    push @array, $_;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Accept input until it finds the word `end`

Solution1

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<>)  {  
    last if $_=~/end/i;  
    push @array,$_;  
}  

for (my $i=scalar(@array);$i>=0;$i--){  
    print pop @array;  
}
```

Solution2

```
while(<>){  

       last if $_=~/end/i;  
       push @array,$_;  

}  

print reverse(@array);
```